# Convert a decimal from a SQL table to a percent in ListView with C#

Tags: c#, sql, listview, format

What I am trying to do is take the values from a SQL Query and display it in a ListView - which I have successfully done with the code below, which has worked well. However, what I need to do is convert ceaPercentage and boxPercentage from the decimals that they are in the SQL table into a percentage that is displayed in the ListView.

```
 try
        {
                connect.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    string prevItem = string.Empty;
                    ListViewGroup currGroup = null;
                    int row = 0;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["WO"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["StartQty"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["Assembly"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["Mfg Family"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["ceaQty"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["ceaPercentage"].ToString("#0.##%"));
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["boxQty"].ToString());
                        item.SubItems.Add(reader["boxPercentage"].ToString());

                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                    if (row % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        item.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
                    }
                    row++;

                    }
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Scanlan Planning Tool Failed to Load", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

I tried using the format string of "#0.00%", however I get an error saying that there is no overload for ToString(). Any ideas on what I did wrong? Or on how to do this properly?

Thank you!

Comment: Object's ToString() doesn't support a format provider but Decimal's does so cast to decimal first then ToString()

Comment: ...or use the much more powerful DataGridView which will format it for you